# How receive a HTTP GET for transcribeCallback when recording a call with the verb <record>?

Tags: callback, get, twilio, transcription

How receive a HTTP GET for transcribeCallback when recording a call with the verb  ?

twiml.record({
            action: '/process_recording?callID=,
            method: 'GET',
            timeout: '15',
            maxLength: '120',
            finishOnKey: '*',
            transcribe: 'true',
            playBeep: 'true',
            transcribeCallback: '/process_transcription

I'm getting a GET request on the process_recording url but a POST request on the process_transcription url

I'm using parse Cloud Code to handle the url requests and I'm getting the following error on the express routing from Parse Cloud Code:

Express Routing Error: Cannot POST /process_transcription

Is there any way to make twilio make a GET request instead of a POST request on the transcribeCallback????

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Evangelist here.

I do not believe there is a way to set the method on the [transcription callback](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record). I've not used Parse myself, but I'm pretty sure it can handle POST requests. Could you post some code?